# Adding scenes to Phaser 3 game not working

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I tried to add scenes to my Phaser 3 game.js file (for which you can see the code [here](https://github.com/Juro-dev/Juro-dev.github.io/blob/master/game.js) and which you can see in (very much beta) action [here](https://juro-dev.github.io/)),

according to the

```
let gameScene = new Phaser.Scene('Game');
```

and

```
gameScene.preload = function() {
```

method described [here](https://gamedevacademy.org/phaser-3-tutorial/) and launching them via

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800,800, Phaser.AUTO, 'game-div', {Game});
```

That only resulted in black screens.

Basically, I want to create a start menu and a game over menu by using scenes. Any light-weight alternatives to the method above for adding scenes or creating simple menus are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you've got a mixture of Phaser 2 and Phaser 3 code going on here. Scenes are a Phaser 3 feature only, but your code above and in the file you linked is all Phaser 2 code. So you need to stick to one version or the other, they can't be mixed and matched like this I'm afraid.

Comment: PhotonStorm! You guys are doing awesome work! Being new to Phaser, there was going to be some silly code written along the way and I appreciate your direct feedback. Perhaps you could suggest a side-by-side comparison of syntax differences between version 2 and 3 or any good game template for version 3? I will try to transition fully to version 3 and remove the older bits and pieces from my code. I really want to make this banana fly with all of its Phaser greatness!

Comment: I can recommend this tutorial series: https://gamedevacademy.org/creating-a-phaser-3-template-part-1/

Comment: So I reworked the game based on that template you shared and tried to throw out all the ver. 2 code along the way. The new version (desktop-only) is here: http://dev.jurolytics.blog/pass-the-phaser . That was a nice challenge. Could you point me to a guide to making this mobile-ready?

Answer (score 1):

in `config.scene`, use an array with objects as scenes.

```
var scene1 = {
    key:'scene1_start_screen', preload: function(){},   create: function(){
  //start sceen create, call next scene with
  phaser_game.scene.start('scene2_game_screen');
  //stop this scene with 
  phaser_game.scene.stop('scene1_start_screen');

  },
}
var scene2 = {
    key:'scene2_game_screen',preload: function(){}, create: function(){},
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: "#b9eaff",
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 200 }
        }
    },
    parent: 'game',
    scene: [scene1,scene2]

};
```

Comment: Thank you, but all I get is an empty game (background and size are fine) with config.scene still not working. Can it be because I am using only one scene for now? I tried running MainScene instead of an array, but the game does not progress beyond showing the background.

Comment: Every scene must be an object with functions create, update, preload, etc. Create another scene and place both inside an array in config.scene